# How do I move an element across the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use HTML and CSS to make a paragraph tag move form left to right when the user clicks it. How can I do something like this?

Comment: Have you tried this yet? Post your code, give us something to work with. We are here to answer questions however we are not here to code it for you.

Comment: The answer I provided is a generic approach to moving elements with jQuery, but like @AdamBuchananSmith said, we need to see what you have tried so we can help you from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's **`animate`** to move elements. Check the following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".text-box").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
```

```css
.text-box{
  background:#98bf21;
  height:auto;
  max-width:400px;
  width:auto;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Move Element!!</button>



<div class="text-box""><p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p></div>
```